# Python Selenium error: "WebDriverException: 'login' executable needs to be in PATH."

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I need to use Selenium to scrape data from a website, and, after pip installing selenium and adding the chrome driver to my PATHs, I get an error. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('https://secure.consumerreports.org/ec/login')

username = driver.find_element_by_id("signin-username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("signin-password")

username.send_keys("myname@university.edu")
password.send_keys("pa$$w0rd")

driver.find_element_by_id('signin-btn').click()

print('Login complete.')
```

And I get:

```
WebDriverException: 'login' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Just to make sure, I pip installed selenium through the terminal, which was successful, and I downloaded the chrome driver for mac (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), unzipped it, and pasted the driver itself into my PATHs. I entered `echo $PATH` in  the terminal, and it printed: `/Users/[my name]/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin`. I was not allowed to paste the driver in `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, and `/sbin`, but the other PATHs were fine.

Based on the error message, it seems like I have to download some kind of 'login' driver in order to be able to log in. I've been unsuccessful in finding such a driver.

I'm new to Selenium, and I'm not sure what to do next. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the path you are giving to `webdriver.Chrome()` should be the path of the executable or nothing if you already provide the right folder in your PATHS.

Then you use the method `get` to access the url you want to scrape

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://secure.consumerreports.org/ec/login')
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given above is correct. You should provide the path to the ChromeDriver that you downloaded from the link mentioned above.

For example, create a folder name ChromeDriver on your desktop and unzip the executable there. Then provide the path as

```
chrome_path  = '/Users/[yourname]/Desktop/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
```

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer